# How to substitute table name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a "common" grid with parameters.
The problem is that in the Delete action I cannot refer to the table as a variable
I use edmx model.

```
public ActionResult PartialView_GridCommonDelete(System.Int64 data_autoinc)
{
    var table = ViewBag.CurrentTable;
    var key= ViewBag.Key;

    if (data_autoinc != null)
    {
        try
        {
            //ERROR HERE
            var item = **ent.table**.FirstOrDefault(it => it.product_autoinc == data_autoinc);
            if (item != null)
                ent.tabla.Remove(item);
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
        }
    }

    return PartialView("PartialView_GridCommon", ViewBag.CurrentSql);
}
```

How can I dynamically substitute the table name so as I can use it with many tables?

Thank you

Comment: Can comment *generally* on this issue that, if your table class in inherited from a base class, you can use that base class in place of table name, or perhaps an interface.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give me a simple example? I'm a beginner in c#.

Comment: What have you got in `ViewBag.CurrentTable`? You can try `ViewBag.CurrentTable.FirstOrDefault(it => it.product_autoinc == data_autoinc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not achievable by ORM i.e. defining Table at runtime.

What you can try is:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

You can explicitly pass table name and fire your sql query

Give it a try.

Thanks
Nipun